# Using Git with a Windows shared network drive

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to introduce Git version control to my team for our UFT scripts in order to better manage the scripts.

The issue I have is that these scripts are currently stored on one of our Windows shared drives - this is where the 'remote repo' would be stored - and the general consensus is that the files in question should stay there and not be moved to a Git server.

This in my view results in complications, such as the ability for anyone with the network access (everybody in the department) to bypass Git and make their own changes and as a result make using Git kind of pointless.

Does anybody out there have any experience of a similar situation or have any advice?

Comment: Yes, decide what you want. This is a discussion you need to take internally. If your team is unwilling to give up everybody-can-modify-the-scripts-all-willy-nilly rights, there's nothing you can do about it as someone will always find a way.

Comment: There's plenty of questions here on Stack Overflow that shows teams with similar problems. People have set up a git repository with a working folder on their server so they can push changes to the master branch and they will automatically be checked out, only to come back here with questions about why pushing stops working because someone (still) edited the files manually on the server. You either need to commit to having this workflow, or you don't, there is no middle ground.